# WUInstall - How to survive WSUS group membership change

Tags: windows-update, wsus

Is there any ready way to apply a WSUS group membership change using registry changes on the client computer **without** requiring a windows update service restart, something like a soft reload for Apache?

I'm working with WUInstall and I'd like to change the group memberships to be analyzed after the next reboot without  disrupting the current operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the lack of response my guess is there isn't a ready way to do this.

Answer (score -2):

There isn't a way to do this, without restarting the Windows Update Service.  Although it's relatively painless to stop and start the Windows Update Service.

```
net stop wuauserv
```

and

```
net start wuauserv
```